# Android Studio can't import Adapter

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, listadapter

I'm not really sure whether this is an issue with my code, or a bug with Android studio. I'm trying to instantiate my adapter for a recyclerview in my main activity. It's in the package adapters, but I tried it with being in the same directory as activity and the problem still occurs.

Android Studio suggests to import the adapter (Alt-Enter) but after I do that, literally nothing happens. importing it manually doesn't work either, I get "Unresolved reference: TodoAdapter". It's almost like the file doesn't exist, despite being clearly there.

I tried everything: making the adapter public, invalidating my caches, using another pc, the problem is still the same.

Here's my code:

TodoAdapter:

```
public class TodoAdapter : ListAdapter<Todo, TodoAdapter.ViewHolder>(TodoDiffCallBack()){
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(ListItemTodoBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val todo = getItem(position)
        holder.apply {
            bind(createOnClickListener(todo.id), todo)
            itemView.tag = todo
        }
    }

    private fun createOnClickListener(todoId: Int): View.OnClickListener {
        return View.OnClickListener {
            Log.v("its working!","workssss")
        }
    }

    class ViewHolder(
        private val binding: ListItemTodoBinding
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){
        fun bind(listener: View.OnClickListener, item: Todo) {
            binding.apply {
                clickListener = listener
                todo = item
                executePendingBindings()
            }
        }
    }

    private class TodoDiffCallBack : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Todo>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Todo, newItem: Todo): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Todo, newItem: Todo): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
    }
}
```

(No errors in that class, and binding works)

And here's my MainActivity

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import com.test.myapp.adapters.TodoAdapter //unresolved reference here as well!
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders
import com.test.myapp.util.Injectors
import com.test.myapp.viewmodels.TodoListViewModel
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
...

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
...
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
           setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

           val adapter = TodoAdapter() //Unresolved reference!
   }
...
}
```

Comment: Show imports in MainActivity, please. A problem may be in other imports, even in `R`. Also you can for experiment move TodoAdapter to MainActivity. And what is `adapter`, what type?

Comment: @CoolMind added the imports. Weirdly enough, the adapter shows up as (<root>) (where the package name should be instead) whatever that means. Obviously it should be a ListAdapter, see code above.

Comment: @CoolMInd inserted it as a private class into my main activity, and it suddenly works. certainly weird

Comment: I also sometimes face this problem. AS can mix `R` and doesn't see other classes.

Comment: Well, if in private class no errors are found and it is built, you can commit the work. Probably you can remove old class `TodoAdapter` and move private TodoAdapter outside of MainActivity (I don't remember, for instance, select it, press F6, select `Move nested class TodoAdapter to upper level`).

Comment: If you do `invalidate caches and restart`, then it was a bug in AS. If it still doesn't work, then it's a bug in your code

Comment: @EpicPandaForce the question would be what exactly my bug here is. as I said, it works as a private inner class in my activity, so I'm leaning more towards AS bug.

Comment: Maybe you are just modularizing too much and using `implementation` instead of `api` in your Gradle configuration, who knows